# Receive SMS using Arduino Nano and Quectel EC25

Tags: arduino-nano, gsm, uart

I'm trying to use an `Arduino Nano` to communicate with a Quectel EC25 module from this [Raspberry Pi 4G HAT](https://sixfab.com/product/raspberry-pi-base-hat-3g-4g-lte-minipcie-cards/). I'm using Arduino's pins 8 and 7 to communicate with RX and TX from the Quectel module. I'm able to establish communication and send AT commands.

The problem is that when I start to listen for incoming SMS, the available method does not change status, even if an SMS is received. There is the code I using:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define DEBUG Serial
SoftwareSerial EC25(8,7); // RX, TX - 9600 baud rate

#define AT_RESPONSE_LEN 100
#define TIMEOUT 1000

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  EC25.begin(9600);
  DEBUG.begin(9600);

  sendATComm("ATE1","OK\r\n");
  sendATComm("AT","OK\r\n");
  sendATComm("AT+IPR?","OK\r\n");
  sendATComm("AT+CGSN","OK\r\n");

  sendATComm("AT+CNMI=2,1","OK\r\n");
  DEBUG.println("listennig");

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:


  if (EC25.available()){
    DEBUG.println("Available");
  }



}

// function for sending at command.
const char* sendATComm(const char *command, const char *desired_reponse)
{
  uint32_t timer;
  char response[AT_RESPONSE_LEN]; // module response for AT commands.

  memset(response, 0 , AT_RESPONSE_LEN);
  EC25.flush();

  sendATCommOnce(command);

  timer = millis();
   while(true){
    if(millis()-timer > TIMEOUT){
      sendATCommOnce(command);
      timer = millis();
    }
    char c;
    int i = 0;

    while(EC25.available()){
      c = EC25.read();
      DEBUG.write(c);
      response[i++]=c;
      delay(2);
      }
      if(strstr(response, desired_reponse)){
        return response;
        memset(response, 0 , strlen(response));
        break;
      }
  }
}

// send at comamand to module
void sendATCommOnce(const char *comm)
{
  EC25.print(comm);
  EC25.print("\r");
}
```

That gives the following output:

```
ATE1

OK
AT

OK
AT+IPR?

+IPR: 9600

OK
AT+CGSN

860548040717545

OK
AT+CNMI=2,1

OK
listennig
```

I also tried this [example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/GSMExamplesReceiveSMS) by changing the default RX and TX pins but does not work at all.